# I couldn't upload the .prpt file in Pentaho user console

Tags: pentaho

When I tried to upload the .prpt file in Pentaho user console,the .prpt file didn't added.  i got the error java.lang.NullPointerException 
in following URL "Repository Upload Log"

http://localhost:8080/pentaho/mantle691FF659CA7BEFEDFF2B993A3F64A706.cache.html

Comment: could you please share more details on the log ?? NullPointer exception could be for many other reasons !!. Not sure on your specific issue. Better try showing some more info / screenshot of the log.!!

Comment: @Rishu Actually he works with me in the same company and saw the issue. ;) What happened there was he tried to upload a prpt to PUC but as soon as he clicks the upload button a window pops up saying "java.lang.NullPointerException" its URL is mentioned above and it has been named as "Repository Upload Log". This worked fine till last Friday but suddenly this issue came. The upload fails. We are clueless!

Comment: @Rishu Now it's works fine , I rebooted the Pentaho's BA server didn't work, then  I login as root user and  rebooted  the server (Command : reboot now), it works fine . i don't know the reason for this issue.

Comment: @Pirinthan ohh great... i assume it might be issue with the repository connectivity !!